# How to access a ListView's ListModel's ListElement's mapped delegate's data in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Essentially, I have an usual ListView:

```
Rectangle {
    id: mylist

    ListModel {
        id: mylistModel
        ListElement {
            text: "blah1"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "blah2"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "blah3"
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: mylistDelegate

        Text {
            id: mylistDelegateText
            text: text
            property bool mylistDelegateTextEnabled: false
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: mylistView
        model: mylistModel
        delegate: mylistDelegate
    }
}
```

Please ignore any problems I might have introduced by truncating the code to focus on what's important.

Anyway, now my problem is that I want to access a ListElement's assigned delegate and see what  the value of mylistDelegateTextEnabled is in a javascript loop. For instance, this loop iterates over current list and gives me the text of the ListElements in the model:

```
for(var i = 0; i < mylistModel.count; ++i) {
    console.log(mylistModel.get(i).text);
}
```

This obviously works fine.

Now what I want is essentially this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < mylistModel.count; ++i) {
    console.log(mylistModel.get(i).text);
    console.log(mylistModel.get(i).delegate.mylistDelegateTextEnabled);
}
```

Alas, that it doesn't seem to be that easy.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't access delegates in that way because they are *transient* objects that are created and destroyed at the discretion of the `ListView`.  As explained in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-listview.html#delegate-prop) for delegates:

> Delegates are instantiated as needed and may be destroyed at any time.
>   State should never be stored in a delegate.

Is there a particular reason why you can't just add a `textEnabled` flag to the `ListModel`? For example:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: mylist
    width:300
    height:300

    ListModel {
        id: mylistModel
        ListElement {
            name: "blah1"
            textEnabled:false
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "blah2"
            textEnabled:false
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "blah3"
            textEnabled:false
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: mylistDelegate

        Text {
            id: mylistDelegateText
            text: name
            color: textEnabled?"red":"black"


            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill:parent;
                onClicked: {
                    mylistModel.setProperty(index, "textEnabled", !textEnabled);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: mylistView
        model: mylistModel
        delegate: mylistDelegate
        width:100;
        height:100

    }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried that and get Error: Cannot assign to read-only property "textEnabled". Yes, I'd like to do assign from QML instead of JS. Can I do that?

Comment: I think from the error you are trying to set the `textEnabled` flag from within the delegate which won't work.  Instead, update the model directly using `model.setProperty()`.  I will update my answer to demonstrate it this way rather than using `Component.onCompleted`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:-

```js
 for (var i = 0; i < mylistView.count; i ++) {
      // this will get list item at index i
      console.log(mylistView.contentItem.children[i]);

      // lets set it height to 100
      mylistView.contentItem.children[i].height=100;
   }
```

Hope this helps,
cheers!!!
@navi